# Jest tests with enzyme and connect() giving `import connectAdvanced from '../components/connectAdvanced';`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am having troubles running a simple `jest/enzyme` test when using connect on a component. I have tried to use `dive()` as suggested here: [Testing a Redux-connected component using Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1002). But still the error is exactly the same.

I would like to be able to test components that are wrapped with shallow and not this error (obviously)

## Console Failure

```
 FAIL  src/containers/Home/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /var/www/cloud/websites/www/node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/connect.js:5
    import connectAdvanced from '../components/connectAdvanced';
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/shared/buttons/index.js:3:16)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.482s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

## home.index.js

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import ButtonUI from '../../components/shared/buttons';

export default class Home extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonUI galabel="testLabel" gaaction="testAction">
        Fire GA Test
      </ButtonUI>
    );
  }
}
```

## components/shared/buttons/index.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect';

class ButtonUI extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <button>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(ButtonUI);
```

## home/index.test.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import Home from './index.js';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

const wrapper = shallow(<Home />).dive();

describe('Home Page Can Render', () => {
  it('Contains a header', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('h5')).to.have.lengthOf(1)
  });
});
```

## Package.json

```
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"connected-react-router": "^4.4.1",
"enzyme": "^3.6.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`connect` is imported as an es6 module and `NodeJS` runtime doesn't know what to do with it.

```
import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect';
```

Usually library authors have their library [transpiled in commonjs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.0/package.json#L31) for interoperability with  multiple environments and [provide that as the entry point for their module](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.0/package.json#L21)

While you can update your bundler configuration to also transpile module imports from the `node_modules` folder, I suggest to use the module entrypoint instead as it's more straightforward that way.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. soooo... I need to this to the `index.test.js`? and then... just add it to the component?

Comment: Updating the import in `components/shared/buttons/index.js` should suffice.